# PostgreSQL: How to switch database inside cursor script

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I want to write function for postgresql 10 to grant read-only access to on all databases for the specified user (considerably should be run from superuser)

But I have difficulties in  database switching part. I try to switch the database inside a cursor but I get an error I can't understand. How can I correct my script?

> CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block at EXECUTE

```
DO $$
DECLARE query text;

cursor cursor
FOR
SELECT '\c '||datname ||';'  from pg_database;
BEGIN
OPEN cursor;
LOOP
    FETCH cursor INTO query;
    EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
    
    --raise notice 'Value: %',query;
    EXECUTE query;
END LOOP;
CLOSE cursor;
END $$;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PL/pgSQL is server language. `\c` meta command is psql feature. PostgreSQL server know nothing about `\c` command.

This is a task for some client application. It is impossible to read or change something in another database. Connection is always open only for one database.

However, you can use [`dblink`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/contrib-dblink-function.html) to open connection to another database and initiate execution of arbitrary commands in that database. dblink will act as a simple libpq client.